# Python cannot import libsvm

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

I know the question was asked many many times but none of the solutions really helped me.

I use spyder, python 3.4 under windows 7/64bit. I managed to install scikit-learn package 0.16.1 with anaconda and after I run `from sklearn import svm` I get the message :

```
"File "MyPC...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 8, in <module> from . import libsvm, liblinear
ImportError: cannot import name 'libsvm' "`
```

However, libsvm is supposed to be installed in the sklearn package..?

Can someone please give me an advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My understanding is that scikit learn links with the libsvm binaries (compiled from c++) to do it's calculation, not that libsvm is installed as python library itself.

Comment: I did already install the binaries..

Answer (score 3):

This must be a link problem.

Close spyder and every python consol
Then open a terminal and write "conda install -f scikit-learn"
This should work afterwards
If you still have linking problems force reinstalling the same way the packages which output import errors

Cheers!